# How to make a div move on the HTML page and not go to the next level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a created divs on a row and now when I zoom them, the following divs move down the page. I don't want them to move to next level, instead I want the HTML width should increase and they should stay at the same level. I have found a jsfiddle for something that I have created for my practice stuff. If you click on the image, they get zoomed and after some zooms, the right hand side image moves down the next level. For me, this should not happen. How to do this?

The link to jsFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/bq6Ju/14/
The below code is written by one of the stack overflow scholar, and this is something what I have a similar in my test application

```
              .flower {
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.flower img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.flower div {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}

.chunk2 div {
left: -100px;
}
.chunk3 div {
top: -100px;
}
.chunk4 div {
top: -100px;
left: -100px;
}
```

The HTML code is

[image]


[image]


[image]


[image]

Javascript/Jquery code is

```
$('div.flower').click(function(){

var resize = 1.30;

var $this = $(this);
var $inner = $this.find('div');

$this.animate({          
    'width': $this.width() * resize,
    'height': $this.width() * resize,   
});

var p = {
    top: parseInt($inner.css('top')),
    left: parseInt($inner.css('left'))
}
console.log(p);
$inner.animate({
    'width': $inner.width() * resize,
    'height': $inner.width() * resize,
    'top': p.top*resize,
    'left': p.left*resize,        
});   

});
```

Comment: What do you want to happen with them?

Comment: If your website layout breaks because the user zooms the page, its their fault not yours. If the user needs to zoom the page to read/see content, it's your fault not theirs.

Comment: @barlasapaydin: there is a fiddle link above. I a pasting the link again http://jsfiddle.net/bq6Ju/14/

Comment: @unix_user Please also add you **relevant** code right here on SO. This way your question would still be valid even if the link goes down for whatever reason.

Comment: @PeeHaa:Assume all images are at level 1. When you go on clicking the image, the right hand side image move down the level and will go to level 2. What I want is the image should not move down, instead the HTML page should go on expanding or the width should get increased and all the images should be at level 1 itself

Comment: So basically you want a horizontal scrollbar to appear?

Comment: @PeeHaa: yes something like that

Comment: @zzzzBov: I am providing the zoom functionality and in it the divs are going to next level and i dont want to happen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a container around the images and prevent wrapping and add scrollbars by the overflow proprty:

```
.container { overflow: auto; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Not that in order to get this working I've removed the `float`, because that prevents you AFAIK from doing what you want. And I have changed the `display` property to `inline-block`. I've also added the `vertical-align` property to make sure the images are always top aligned.

```
.flower {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bq6Ju/18/

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is what I need to do, but I do not want to remove the float from css as I am having more than 100 such divs, and I need them to be placed in a grid like structure. Any other approach, in which the grid like str is also present and the divs also do not go to next level?

Comment: Wouldn't `inline-block` still produce the grid you are after?

Comment: no it doesnt.If i remove float: left the grid goes away and the div gets overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a floated container with `nowrap` works too.

http://jsfiddle.net/bq6Ju/19/

```
.container {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: :This is already done. I need the images to not to move down i.e. horizontal scrollbar should come down.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome, i.e. images just keep moving right, though it does seem to break in IE8 and the images move down.

Comment: ok. I tried in firefox and is not working for me in that. Any idea how to do this in ff??

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bq6Ju/26/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="row_wrapper">
  <div class="flower chunk1">
    <div>
      <img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flower chunk2">
    <div>
      <img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flower chunk3">
    <div>
      <img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flower chunk4">
    <div>
      <img src="http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- and here more rows -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.row {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.row_wrapper {
  width: 500px; /* initial width */
}

/* other your css */
```

**JavaScript**

```
// in click handler

var total_width = 0;
var cur_outer = $(this).outerWidth(true) - $(this).width();
var cur_inner = resize * $(this).width();
var total_width = cur_outer + cur_inner;

$(this).parent().children('.flower').not(this).each(function () {
  total_width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

$(this).parent().width(total_width + 10);
```